# I am trying to make a Mineflayer bot for Authme Servers

Tags: javascript, mineflayer

My Mineflayer code is not registering in Authme servers.

I have an Authme Server I need my bot to farm in it . I was searching code from Youtube, Google, ChatGPT. I tried doing my own in which it registers account in authme but it getting kicked from the server for login timeout exceeded I dont know What to do anyone please help .

This is my Index.js

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const Movements = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').Movements;
const pathfinder = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').pathfinder;
const { GoalBlock } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder').goals;


const config = require('./settings.json');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Bot is arrived')
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});

function createBot() {
  const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
     username: config['bot-account']['username'],
     password: config['bot-account']['password'],
     auth: config['bot-account']['type'],
     host: config.server.ip,
     port: config.server.port,
     version: config.server.version,
  });

  bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder);
  const mcData = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version);
  const defaultMove = new Movements(bot, mcData);
  bot.settings.colorsEnabled = false;

  bot.once('spawn', () => {
     console.log('\x1b[33m[AfkBot] Bot joined to the server', '\x1b[0m');

     if (config.utils['auto-auth'].enabled) {
        console.log('[INFO] Started auto-auth module');

        var password = config.utils['auto-auth'].password;
        setTimeout(() => {
           bot.chat(`/register ${password} ${password}`);
           bot.chat(`/login ${password}`);
        }, 500);

        console.log(`[Auth] Authentification commands executed.`);
     }

     if (config.utils['chat-messages'].enabled) {
        console.log('[INFO] Started chat-messages module');
        var messages = config.utils['chat-messages']['messages'];

        if (config.utils['chat-messages'].repeat) {
           var delay = config.utils['chat-messages']['repeat-delay'];
           let i = 0;

           let msg_timer = setInterval(() => {
              bot.chat(`${messages[i]}`);

              if (i + 1 == messages.length) {
                 i = 0;
              } else i++;
           }, delay * 1000);
        } else {
           messages.forEach((msg) => {
              bot.chat(msg);
           });
        }
     }

     const pos = config.position;

     if (config.position.enabled) {
        console.log(
           `\x1b[32m[Afk Bot] Starting moving to target location (${pos.x}, ${pos.y}, ${pos.z})\x1b[0m`
        );
        bot.pathfinder.setMovements(defaultMove);
        bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalBlock(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
     }

     if (config.utils['anti-afk'].enabled) {
        bot.setControlState('jump', true);
        if (config.utils['anti-afk'].sneak) {
           bot.setControlState('sneak', true);
        }
     }
  });

  bot.on('chat', (username, message) => {
     if (config.utils['chat-log']) {
        console.log(`[ChatLog] <${username}> ${message}`);
     }
  });

  bot.on('goal_reached', () => {
     console.log(
        `\x1b[32m[AfkBot] Bot arrived to target location. ${bot.entity.position}\x1b[0m`
     );
  });

  bot.on('death', () => {
     console.log(
        `\x1b[33m[AfkBot] Bot has been died and was respawned ${bot.entity.position}`,
        '\x1b[0m'
     );
  });

  if (config.utils['auto-reconnect']) {
     bot.on('end', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
           createBot();
        }, config.utils['auto-recconect-delay']);
     });
  }

  bot.on('kicked', (reason) =>
     console.log(
        '\x1b[33m',
        `[AfkBot] Bot was kicked from the server. Reason: \n${reason}`,
        '\x1b[0m'
     )
  );
  bot.on('error', (err) =>
     console.log(`\x1b[31m[ERROR] ${err.message}`, '\x1b[0m')
  );
}

createBot()
```

This is my settings.json

```
{
  "bot-account": {
    "username": "User123",
    "password": "",
    "type": "mojang"
  },
  "server": {
    "ip": "################",
    "port": 39092,
    "version": "1.16.5"
  },
  "utils": {
    "auto-auth": {
      "enabled": true,
      "password": "Mypassword"
    },
    "chat-messages": {
      "enabled": true,
      "repeat": true,
      "repeat-delay": 10,
      "messages": [
        "Hi",
        "Pro User here"
      ]
    },
    "anti-afk": {
      "enabled": false,
      "sneak": true
    },
    "auto-reconnect": true,
    "auto-reconnect-delay": 5000
  },
  "position": {
    "enabled": true,
    "x": 100,
    "y": 64,
    "z": 200
  }
}
```

anyhelp please

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had made a bot before.. So for using it on Authme servers all you have to do is put if condition command upcoming messages on your bot if its /login it shouild do the /login command and if it is /register it should use the /register command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).